# Skip line if is determined character

Tags: c, file, io

I'm trying to read the first character of a file and whenever it's equal to `'('` I should skip that line else get the first character from that line. I'm under a mac and I can make use of `fgetln`.

```
FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

char c;
while(fscanf(file, "%s", &c) != EOF) {
  if (c != '(')
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

That's my current code. I don't know how to skip lines, although I've tried to get the whole line and checked only the first char solving the skip problem. However this is not working I'm getting strange characters in my console instead of the ones inside `test.txt`. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly longer character-based approach, which conditions on whether the first character in a line is `(` or not.

If it is `(`, then we consume everything up to and including the next newline without outputting.

If it not, then we do the same thing but we output the characters as we read them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    int c;
    while((c = getc(file)) != -1) {
        if (c == '(') {
            // Skip until the next newline
            do {
                c = getc(file);
            } while (c != -1 && c != '\n');
            continue;
        }
        else {
            putchar(c);
            do {
                c = getc(file);
                putchar(c);
            } while (c != -1 && c != '\n');
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using `%s` format specifier of `fscanf` is that is splits on spaces, not only on end-of-line characters. Moreover, reading it in a single-character buffer will *nearly always* produce undefined behavior.

There are several ways to solve this problem, using different APIs:

- You could replace `%s` with `%200[^\n]`, and passing a 201-character buffer instead of `c`,
- Using `fgets` with a properly-sized buffer, and picking the initial character, or
- Using a character-based API, and setting a "take next" flag each time that you see a `'\n'` character:

Here is how you can implement the third approach:

```
bool takeNext = true;
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
    if (takeNext && ch != '(') {
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
    takeNext = (ch == '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change c to string because fscanf reads string. See if the 1st character of c matches with `(`.

If it does not then print the line else skip the line.

```
FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

char c[100];
while(fscanf(file, "%s", c)) {
if (c[0] != '(')
    printf("%s", c);
}
```

Comment: You need to add some explanatory text about why this is the solution. Code only answers are discouraged here.

Answer (score 0):

Use fgets to read whole lines. It is also safer than fscanf as it limits the reading to the buffer size.

To check if the first char is '(' you can refer to it directly:

```
if (buf[0]=='(')
```

or

```
if (*buf=='(')
```